# Booting Ubuntu from USB Press tab

Tags: grub2, live-usb, bootloader

When I boot my computer with a bootable USB, on the first screen many options appear:
Try Ubuntu,
Install Ubuntu,
Check memory,
etc.

But at the end, it says "Press Tab to edit". Out of curiosity I pressed the tab key while "check memory for defects" was highlighted, and wrote, randomly, "defects", and then pressed enter. The screen then started showing the Ubuntu logo and some kind of log that looked like it was indeed checking the memory for defects.

My question is
What's the purpose/meaning of "edit" in the option "Press tab to edit"? Press the tab key to edit what exactly?

Thank you

EDIT: I used Unetbootin to make the USB bootable. I think the link in sudodus's comment answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Things may look differently depending on how you created the USB boot drive (which bootloader you are using and how it is configured). How did you create your bootable USB drive? Which tool did you use? - The reason to edit the boot sequence is that you may want to change or add some **boot option(s)**. See this link and links from it, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: Grub uses "e" to start edits.  Maybe you are talking about the syslinux bootloader, or some other.  The grub tag may be misleading.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad that the link in my comment was useful :-)

Comment: @sudodus can you please write a formal answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things may look differently depending on how you created the USB boot drive (which bootloader you are using and how it is configured).

- You used Unetbootin to make the USB bootable. In BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) syslinux will be used as bootloader. In UEFI mode grub will be used as bootloader. There will be different boot menus depending on the boot mode (BIOS or UEFI), but in both cases you are able to edit the boot sequence.
- The reason to edit the boot sequence is that you may want to change or add some boot option(s).

  See this link and links from it, [Boot Options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808)